# Longest string that can be made out of a list of strings

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, concatenation

I'm looking for an efficient algorithm which will give me the longest string which can be made out of a list of strings. More precisely:

Given a file containing large number of strings, find the longest string from the list of strings presented in the file, which is a concatenation of other one or more strings.

Note: The answer string should also belong to the list of strings in file.

Example input:

```
The
he
There
After
ThereAfter
```

Output:

```
ThereAfter
```

Comment: So have you got an inefficient one?

Comment: Sort your strings by length and build a prefix tree starting from the shortest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort list in descending length order for strings in the list (first in the list is longest string). Quicksort is sorting with average time complexity O(nlogn).

Then, iterate on strings in the list starting left.

From string S, iterate on elements s to its right. If s is a substring of S, remove s from S. Continue iterating to the right until S is empty, meaning that it is made of items of the list.

```
public static class ListCompare implements Comparator<String> {
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        if (s1.length() < s2.length())
            return 1;
        else if (s1.length() > s2.length())
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}

public static String longestSurString(String[] ss) {
    Arrays.sort(ss, new ListCompare ());
    for (String S: ss) {
        String b = new String(s);
        for (String s: ss) {
            if (!s.equals(b) && S.contains(s)) {
                S = S.replace(s, "");
            }
        }
        if (S.length() == 0)
            return b;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: `["ThereAfterThemath", "AfterThem", "There", "math", "The", "he"]` If this is the sorted array, your solution will return null whereas the answer should be "ThereAfterThemath". Please correct me if I am missing anything silly here.

Comment: @trailblazer `"ThereAfterThemath"` is not a composite made up of other words in the list. You can only break `"ThereAfterThemath"` as `["The", "reAfterThemath"]` or `["There", "AfterThemath"]`, but in both cases, even though the prefixes `"The"` and `"There"` are in the list, the suffixes aren't composites made up of other words in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Let us number the strings from `S1, S2, ..., Sn`

If I understand the problem statement correctly, than for `Si`to be a candidate for an answer, it must be equal to the concatenation of some
`Sj_1, Sj_2, ..., Sj_k` where forall `x in 1..k: i != j_x`.  That is `Si` must be the concatenation of a subset of the strings that *it is not a member of*.

Given that, add all the strings to a trie.  This will find all the prefix pairs, that is all `(Si, Sj_1)` from the above.  Removing the `Sj_1` prefix from `Si` renders a new string `T`, that must either be equal to `Sj_k`, or can be similarly reduced by searching for `Sj_2` in the trie.

Comment: This is _really_ hand wavy. No examples, no code, nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

Best Solution using Trie & HashMap data structure:
We need first store all string and then just check prefix which words length is more.

```
public class TrieNode {
private HashMap<Character, TrieNode> children;
private boolean isWord;

public TrieNode() {
    children = new HashMap<>();
    isWord = false;
}

public void add(String s) {

    HashMap<Character,TrieNode> temp_child = children;

    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
        char c = s.charAt(i);

        TrieNode trieNode;
        if(temp_child.containsKey(c)){
            trieNode = temp_child.get(c);
        }else{
            trieNode = new TrieNode();
            temp_child.put(c, trieNode);
        }

        temp_child = trieNode.children;

        //set leaf node
        if(i==s.length()-1)
            trieNode.isWord = true;
    }

}

public boolean isWord(String s) {
    TrieNode trieNode = searchNode(s);

    if(trieNode != null && trieNode.isWord)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public TrieNode searchNode(String s){
    HashMap<Character, TrieNode> temp_child = children;
    TrieNode trieNode = null;
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if(temp_child.containsKey(c)){
            trieNode = temp_child.get(c);
            temp_child = trieNode.children;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    return trieNode;
}
```

Comment: You built a Trie, great, but forgot to show how does that solve the given problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to show an implementation in Python, complete with time complexity analysis. The idea is to split a word at every position, and if the left is in the list of words, recursively check if the right is a composite. Do this for every word. Also, memoize the results to avoid duplicate work.

```
def longest_composite_word(words: list[str]) -> str:
    @functools.lru_cache
    def is_composite(word: str) -> bool:
        if word in uniq_words:
            return True
        for j in range(1, len(word)):
            has_left = word[0:j] in uniq_words
            if has_left and is_composite(word[j:]):
                return True
        return False

    uniq_words = set(words)
    for word in sorted(words, key=len, reverse=True):
        uniq_words.remove(word)
        if is_composite(word):
            return word
        uniq_words.add(word)

    return ""
```

**Time Complexity:** For a word of length `n`, the for-loop runs `n - 1` times. Since each recursive call reduces the problem size by 1, the time taken by the first iteration is `n - 1 + n - 2 + ... + 1 = O(n^2)`.
Second iteration: `n - 2 + n - 3 + ... + 1 = O(n^2)`
Therefore, time taken by `n - 1` iterations is `O(n^3`).

In the worst case, if there are `k` words of length `n`, and every proper prefix of a word is present in the list, like `["a", "aa", "aab"]`, then total time taken by the algorithm is:

```
O(kn^3) + O(k log k) + O(k)
          ^sort^       ^outer loop^
```